# How to remove zeros that not represent a number?

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to build a calculator for practice. im using `eval()` to calculate the result. but im still missing one point (afaik), that is prevent zeros that create non number. for example if i have string

```
7+9+00.98+0.0000089+0009+780000+00.000
```

it cant be evaluated because `00.98` `0009` `00.000` cant be calculated as number. how to prevent this to happen?

her is my codepen https://codepen.io/muhsalaa/pen/eYNjKOo

```js
const button0 = document.getElementById('button-0');
const button1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button-2');
const button3 = document.getElementById('button-3');
const button4 = document.getElementById('button-4');
const button5 = document.getElementById('button-5');
const button6 = document.getElementById('button-6');
const button7 = document.getElementById('button-7');
const button8 = document.getElementById('button-8');
const button9 = document.getElementById('button-9');

const buttonMultiplication = document.getElementById('button-multiplication');
const buttonDivision = document.getElementById('button-division');
const buttonSubtraction = document.getElementById('button-subtraction');
const buttonAddition = document.getElementById('button-addition');
const buttonClear = document.getElementById('button-clear');
const buttonPeriod = document.getElementById('button-period');

const progressText = document.getElementById('progress');
const resultText = document.getElementById('result');

let progress = '';
let result  = 0;

function preventDoubleOperator(x) {
  let alias = progress;
  alias += x;
  let filter = new RegExp(/[-+./*]{2,}/);
  const res = filter.test(alias.slice(-2))

  if (!res) {
    progress += x;
  } else {
    progress = progress.replace(/.$/, x)
  }
  
  progressText.innerHTML = progress;

  setResultText();
}

function setResultText() {
  if (Boolean(parseInt(progress.split('')[progress.length - 1]) + 1)) {
    result = eval(progress);
    if (result % 1 !== 0) {
      result = result.toFixed(4);
    }
  }

  resultText.innerHTML = result;
}

button0.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('0');
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('1')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('2')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button3.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('3')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button4.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('4')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button5.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('5')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button6.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('6')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button7.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('7')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button8.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('8')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button9.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('9')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonMultiplication.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('*')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonDivision.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('/')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonSubtraction.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('-')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonAddition.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('+')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonPeriod.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('.')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonClear.addEventListener('click', function() {
  progress = '';
  result = 0;
  progressText.innerHTML = progress;
  resultText.innerHTML = result;
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quantico:700&display=swap');

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #ece1ef;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 35px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  box-shadow:  6px 6px 20px #c9bfcb, 
              -6px -6px 20px #ffffff;
  border-radius: 19px;
}

.show-data {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  grid-column: span 4;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  word-break: break-all;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 175px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 19px;
  background: #ece1ef;
  box-shadow:  6px 6px 20px #c9bfcb, 
              -6px -6px 20px #ffffff;
}

.progress {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Quantico';
  line-height: 80%;
}

.result {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  font-family: 'Quantico';
}

.button-neumorphic {
  border: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ece1ef;
  box-shadow:  6px 6px 20px #c9bfcb, 
              -6px -6px 20px #ffffff;
}

.button-neumorphic:active,
.button-neumorphic:focus {
  border: none;
  font-size: 27px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ece1ef;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 6px 20px #c9bfcb, 
              inset -6px -6px 20px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="show-data">
      <p id="progress" class="progress"></p>
      <div id="result" class="result">0</div>
    </div>
    <button id="button-1" class="button-neumorphic">1</button>
    <button id="button-2" class="button-neumorphic">2</button>
    <button id="button-3" class="button-neumorphic">3</button>
    <button id="button-multiplication" class="button-neumorphic">*</button>
    <button id="button-4" class="button-neumorphic">4</button>
    <button id="button-5" class="button-neumorphic">5</button>
    <button id="button-6" class="button-neumorphic">6</button>
    <button id="button-division" class="button-neumorphic">/</button>
    <button id="button-7" class="button-neumorphic">7</button>
    <button id="button-8" class="button-neumorphic">8</button>
    <button id="button-9" class="button-neumorphic">9</button>
    <button id="button-addition" class="button-neumorphic">+</button>
    <button id="button-period" class="button-neumorphic">.</button>
    <button id="button-0" class="button-neumorphic">0</button>
    <button id="button-clear" class="button-neumorphic">C</button>
    <button id="button-subtraction" class="button-neumorphic">-</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: They are perfectly good numbers. Why do you mean by "non number"?

Comment: Are there only addition? i.e. + sign?

Comment: @AdrianHHH No, they're not: `00.98` is a SyntaxError (at least in Chrome 80.0.3987.149).

Comment: Then you need to explain that by [edit]ing the question. What is reporting the error? What code are you using and what exactly are the results. Please read the [help] pages for this site and then construct a [mcve]. Codepen links are not sufficient. Put the code in the question.

Comment: @Teemu - It surprises me you're not getting an error in the console. Chrome's console doesn't like them. It's because with a leading zero not immediately followed by a `.`, you're into legacy octal integer literal land, and legacy octal integer literals can't have `.` or `9` in them (and are disallowed entirely in strict mode :-) ). (That said, some engines fall back to decimal for `0009`, heaven help us, creating the situation where `010` is `8` decimal but `019` is `19` decimal. :-D )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm on FF, hitting ENTER after 00.98 doesn't do anything, except creates a new-line ... It looks like the console waits for more input in that case (my console is in single-line mode, though)

Comment: @Amadan - Yes, I mentioned that above.

Comment: @Teemu - I get the same thing with Firefox. Interesting!

Comment: Hm, could you break them on operators, run `parseFloat()` on them and reassemble the equation? (I mean, at that point you could likely do the math with functions anyway …)

Comment: @Teemu @T.JCrowder the question mentions they are using the eval function. Typing `00.98` into the console does act like its waiting for more input (weird), but doing `eval("00.98")` as the question suggests results in the described error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is `progress` (as reported in your code) your should apply this:

```js
// Regex to describe the format of the numbers to replace
const possibleNumberIdentifier = /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g;

// Replacement with the js number format (with automatic concatenation)
const newProgress = progress.replace(possibleNumberIdentifier, x => +x);

eval(newProgress);
```

Btw it's better if you find a way to avoid `eval`.

Let's go deep into the regex:

1. the param `\d` represent a digit (0-9), with the symbol `+` it means 1 or more digit.
2. The dot (`.`) is a particular char in regular expression, but we need the dot from the string, so we need to escape it (as you see I used `\.`)
3. The dot (and decimal numbers) are not present in all numbers, so I need to describe that that part can be with 0 or 1 occurrence, so I grouped the dot and the decimal numbers in a grouper (`(?:\.\d+)`) and I added `?` to describe that the number selection is valid also if that group is not present.
4. I used this group `(?: ... )` instead of this `( ... )` because it will save effort in the calculation under the wood.
5. Last part of regular expression, is the `g` at the end, and it means that the regex is valid not for just first match but for all the match in the string.
6. The `replace` method of js strings is a method that can accept a regular expression and a callback. The callback is called every time in the main string there is a match with the regular expression, is passed as first argument the substring that matches the regex and whatever is returned by the callback will replace the matching substring
7. In js when you have a string like `str = '123'` you can transform it into a number just with the command `num = +str`.
8. When the callback returns a number, it will returns the number in js format, so automatically without the useless `0`.

Please let me know if it's not clear enough and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: Hi @yunzen, I agree that we should not use eval, but he already used in his code and I left it as it was. If it was for me after the `map` I prefer to use a `reduce`

Comment: hi @Raffaele the string will not always `+` , it can be any mahematical operator

Comment: Hi @muhsalaa, sorry I misunderstood your request, I'm updating now the code.

Comment: @Raffaele wow the regex works like charm, and the way to make bad number a good number is amazing, thanks, i'll accept this answer. but can you explain the regex above?

Comment: @Raffaele wow the regex works like charm, and the way to make bad number a good number is amazing, thanks, i'll accept this answer. but can you explain the regex above?

Comment: @muhsalaa, I'll add the comment in main answer, if you consider it the solution you should also click on the gray V that is under the arrow down under the number on left side of my answer. This allow the other use of this web site to understand this is the solution.

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks for the explanation. Actually i clicked the checkmark last time, but it might be a connection prblm. nvrmind

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the second parameter to the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method. You should provide a radix of 10 for the parsing, otherwise the radix is determined automatically and it does not need to be the `10`

```
if (Boolean(parseInt(progress.split('')[progress.length - 1],10) + 1)) {
// _________________________________________________________^^^
```

```js
const button0 = document.getElementById('button-0');
const button1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button-2');
const button3 = document.getElementById('button-3');
const button4 = document.getElementById('button-4');
const button5 = document.getElementById('button-5');
const button6 = document.getElementById('button-6');
const button7 = document.getElementById('button-7');
const button8 = document.getElementById('button-8');
const button9 = document.getElementById('button-9');

const buttonMultiplication = document.getElementById('button-multiplication');
const buttonDivision = document.getElementById('button-division');
const buttonSubtraction = document.getElementById('button-subtraction');
const buttonAddition = document.getElementById('button-addition');
const buttonClear = document.getElementById('button-clear');
const buttonPeriod = document.getElementById('button-period');

const progressText = document.getElementById('progress');
const resultText = document.getElementById('result');

let progress = '';
let result  = 0;

function preventDoubleOperator(x) {
  let alias = progress;
  alias += x;
  let filter = new RegExp(/[-+./*]{2,}/);
  const res = filter.test(alias.slice(-2))

  if (!res) {
    progress += x;
  } else {
    progress = progress.replace(/.$/, x)
  }
  
  progressText.innerHTML = progress;

  setResultText();
}

function setResultText() {
  if (Boolean(parseInt(progress.split('')[progress.length - 1],10) + 1)) {
    result = eval(progress);
    if (result % 1 !== 0) {
      result = result.toFixed(4);
    }
  }

  resultText.innerHTML = result;
}

button0.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('0');
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('1')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('2')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button3.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('3')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button4.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('4')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button5.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('5')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button6.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('6')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button7.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('7')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button8.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('8')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

button9.addEventListener('click', function() {
  preventDoubleOperator('9')
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonMultiplication.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('*')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonDivision.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('/')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonSubtraction.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('-')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonAddition.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('+')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonPeriod.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (progress.length > 0){
    preventDoubleOperator('.')
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})

buttonClear.addEventListener('click', function() {
  progress = '';
  result = 0;
  progressText.innerHTML = progress;
  resultText.innerHTML = result;
  setTimeout(() => this.blur(), 100);
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quantico:700&display=swap');

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #ece1ef;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 35px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  box-shadow:  6px 6px 20px #c9bfcb, 
              -6px -6px 20px #ffffff;
  border-radius: 19px;
}

.show-data {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  grid-column: span 4;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  word-break: break-all;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 175px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 19px;
  background: #ece1ef;
  box-shadow:  6px 6px 20px #c9bfcb, 
              -6px -6px 20px #ffffff;
}

.progress {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Quantico';
  line-height: 80%;
}

.result {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  font-family: 'Quantico';
}

.button-neumorphic {
  border: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ece1ef;
  box-shadow:  6px 6px 20px #c9bfcb, 
              -6px -6px 20px #ffffff;
}

.button-neumorphic:active,
.button-neumorphic:focus {
  border: none;
  font-size: 27px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ece1ef;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 6px 20px #c9bfcb, 
              inset -6px -6px 20px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="show-data">
      <p id="progress" class="progress"></p>
      <div id="result" class="result">0</div>
    </div>
    <button id="button-1" class="button-neumorphic">1</button>
    <button id="button-2" class="button-neumorphic">2</button>
    <button id="button-3" class="button-neumorphic">3</button>
    <button id="button-multiplication" class="button-neumorphic">*</button>
    <button id="button-4" class="button-neumorphic">4</button>
    <button id="button-5" class="button-neumorphic">5</button>
    <button id="button-6" class="button-neumorphic">6</button>
    <button id="button-division" class="button-neumorphic">/</button>
    <button id="button-7" class="button-neumorphic">7</button>
    <button id="button-8" class="button-neumorphic">8</button>
    <button id="button-9" class="button-neumorphic">9</button>
    <button id="button-addition" class="button-neumorphic">+</button>
    <button id="button-period" class="button-neumorphic">.</button>
    <button id="button-0" class="button-neumorphic">0</button>
    <button id="button-clear" class="button-neumorphic">C</button>
    <button id="button-subtraction" class="button-neumorphic">-</button>
  </div>
```